# MatLAB help: shuffling a predefined vector without consecutively repeating numbers (with equal occurrences of all values)

Tags: matlab, random, octave, shuffle

I'm having troubles with randomly shuffling a vector without repeating numbers (ex. 1 1 is not acceptable but 1 2 is acceptable), given that each value is repeated equally.

More specifically, I would like to repeat the matrix `[1:4]` ten times (40 elements in total) so that 1, 2, 3 and 4 would all repeat 10 times without being consecutive.

If there is any clarification needed please let me know, I hope this question was clear.

This is what I have so far:

```
cond_order = repmat([1:4],10,1); %make matrix
cond_order = cond_order(:); %make sequence
```

I know randperm is quite relevant but I'm not sure how to use it with the one condition of non-repeating numbers.

EDIT: Thank you for all the responses.

1. I realize I was quite unclear. These are the examples I would like to reject `[1 1 2 2 4 4 4...]`.
   So it doesn't matter if `[1 2 3 4]` occurs in that order as long as individual values are not repeated. (so both `[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4...]` and `[4 3 1 2...]` are acceptable)
2. Preferably I am looking for a shuffled vector meeting the criteria that

   1. it is random
   2. there are no consecutively repeating values (ex. 1 1 4 4)
   3. all four values appear equal amount of times

Comment: Difficult problem, got no better idea than [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) which basically means running above idea with `randperm` until your constrain of non-repeated numbers is satisfied.

Comment: Do you only want to reject `[1 2 3 4]`, or do you also want to reject `[4 3 1 2]` (since `1` and `2` are consecutive)?

Comment: Do you need an equal probability of choosing all feasible sequences? Or do you just need to find a feasible sequence?

Comment: Also, are you going to always have only 4 elements, or will your actual implementation require more? For this small problem it would be feasible to generate all of the possibilities, remove the ones you don't want, and randomly sample from the remainder.

Comment: @beaker that's quite problematic :/ eg. `[1, 2, 2]` only has one possible ordering: `[2 1 2]`. If your algorithm choose `1` first, it's stuck unless you have backtracking. Also, different numbers will have a different number of feasible sequences with that num as the first num. If you want to sample uniformly from feasible sequences, you need to figure out those probabilities! Simple uniform, equal probability of any number being first won't be right... (eg. in `[1, 2, 2]` example, the probability for any number besides 2 being first is 0). Maybe you can effectively get that with backtracking?

Comment: @MatthewGunn I'm talking about generating all permutations of the vector and rejecting the ones you consider invalid. No backtracking is necessary. What to do with duplicate elements is something you have to deal with whenever you're generating permutations. Are `[2 2 1]` and `[2 2 1]` distinct? Depending on the answer to my first question, `[2 1 2]` might not be a valid solution at all.

Comment: Please do not remove the text from your answered question! The questions are not answered exclusively for you, same users having the same problem should have access to it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution from [mikkola](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005117/2732801) got it methodically right, but I think there is a more efficient way:

He chose to sample based on equal quantities and check for the difference. I chose to do it the other way round and ended up with a solution requiering much less iterations.

```
n=4;
k=10;
d=42; %// random number to fail first check
while(~all(sum(bsxfun(@eq,d,(1:n).'),2)==k)) %' //Check all numbers to appear k times.
    d=mod(cumsum([randi(n,1,1),randi(n-1,1,(n*k)-1)]),n)+1; %generate new random sample, enforcing a difference of at least 1.
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Kind of working with the rejection sampling idea, just repeating with `randperm` until a sequence permutation is found that has no repeated values.

```
cond_order = repmat(1:4,10,1); %//make matrix
N = numel(cond_order); %//number of elements
sequence_found = false;
while ~sequence_found
    candidate = cond_order(randperm(N));
    if all(diff(candidate) ~= 0) %// check if no repeated values
        sequence_found = true;
    end
end
result = candidate;
```

Comment: This will work for a matrix of 40 elements, but would quickly get computationally infeasible. My answer is basically a more reliable method that doesn't throw the whole iteration away each time it doesn't match (which would be most iterations).

Comment: Works for small problems! As I think about it, generating an equal chance of each feasible sequence gets extremely tricky if you don't do it this way :/ I'm not sure many people reading the problem fully appreciate that aspect...

Comment: @zelanix agreed on the size aspect. The answer depends on the distribution one wants to sample from, this one as mentioned is uniform (among the sequences that satisfy the given constraint).

Comment: @mikkola I'm not sure if you're up for it, but we've had a MATLAB chat room going for a while: chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave - whenever you like, drop by and say hello. It's nice to see a new active MATLAB user around. They're few and far in between!

Answer (score 3):

#### A subtle but important distinction: does the author need an equal probability of picking any feasible sequence?

A number of people have mentioned answers of the form, "Let's use randperm and then rearrange the sequence so that it's feasible." That may not work. What will make this problem quite hard is if the author needs an equal chance of choosing any feasible sequence. Let me give an example to show the problem.

Imagine the set of numbers `[1 2 2 3 4]`. First lets enumerate the set of feasible sequences:

- 6 sequences beginning with 1:  `[1 2 3 2 4], [1 2 3 4 2], [1 2 4 2 3], [1 2 4 3 2], [1 3 2 4 2], [1 4 2 3 2]`.
- Then there are 6 sequences beginning with [2 1]: `[2 1 2 3 4], [2 1 2 4 3], [2 1 3 2 4], [2 1 3 4 2], [2 1 4 2 3], [2 1 4 3 2]`. By symmetry, there are 18 sequences beginning with 2 (i.e. 6 of [2 1], 6 of [2 3], 6 of [2 4]).
- By symmetry there are 6 sequences beginning with 3 and another 6 starting with 4.
- Hence there are 6 * 3 + 18 = 36 possible sequences.

Sampling uniformly from feasible sequences, the probability the first number is 2 is 18/36 = 50 percent! BUT if you just went with a random permutation, the probability the first digit is 2 would be 40 percent! (i.e. 2/5 numbers in set are 2)

If equal probability of any feasible sequence is required, you want 50 percent of a 2 as the first number, but naive use of `randperm` and then rejiggering numbers at `2:end` to make sequence feasible would give you a 40 percent probability of the first digit being two.

Note that rejection sampling *would* get the probabilities right as every feasible sequence would have an equal probability of being accepted. (Of course rejection sampling becomes very slow as probability of being accepted goes towards 0.)

Comment: Uniform can typically be defined in a very simple way. Let's take the full resulting list as a random variable, all possible realisations should have the same probability, thus 1/36 in your case.

Comment: @daniel Exactly. This is the problem with naive use of randperm, accepting the first number, and rejiggering the rest of array so it's feasible. In this example, the first number should be two 50% of the time (18/36) from uniform distribution over set of feasible sequences, not 40% (2/5) because 2 of the 5 set entries are the number 2.

Comment: @daniel Rejection sampling gets this right. But it's quite tricky to get right otherwise unless someone has something immensely clever (and you would need to prove it mathematically imho).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation :) I can the problem with my answer, but surely in the case where the input vector is uniformly distributed (as per the question), it would be acceptable?

Comment: @zelanix Your method, with backtracking added, would generate a random draw from some probability distribution F over the set of feasible sequences. If all he needs is F to have full support, then your answer is fine. If he needs F to be uniform, then your answer is not fine because F isn't uniform. The constraint on feasible sequences makes it extremely complicated to even begin to think what F is. General point: probability can quickly get EXTREMELY difficult...

Comment: I understand the probability concepts, and I agree that this is a difficult problem to solve! I would hazard a guess that it is NP-Complete. I have performed some extra analysis and added it to my answer. I suspect that there *is* a better algorithm that draws uniform samples efficiently, but finding it probably isn't trivial. Anyway, I have definitely learned something today so thank you!

Comment: One solution could be to use my algorithm as a draw from a 'proposal distribution' then accept or reject it based on the probability of it being one of the biased samples, but of course this only moves the problem to how to generate this probability.

Answer (score 2):

Following some of the discussion on here, I think that there is a trade-off between performance and the theoretical requirements of the application.

If a completely uniform draw from the set of all valid permutations is required, then pure rejection sampling method will probably be required. The problem with this of course is that as the size of the problem is increased, the rejection rate will become very high. To demonstrate this, if we consider the base example in the question being *n* multiples of `[1 2 3 4]` then we can see the number of samples rejected for each valid draw as follows (note the log y axis):

[image]

My alternative method is to randomly sort the array, and then if duplicates are detected then the remaining elements will again be randomly sorted:

```
cond_order = repmat(1:4,10,1); %make matrix
cond_order = reshape(cond_order, numel(cond_order), 1);

cond_order = cond_order(randperm(numel(cond_order)));

i = 2;

while i < numel(cond_order)
    if cond_order(i) ~= cond_order(i - 1)
        i = i + 1;
    else
        tmp = cond_order(i:end);
        cond_order(i:end) = tmp(randperm(numel(tmp)));
    end
end

cond_order
```

Note that there is no guarantee that this will converge, but in the case where is becomes clear that it will not converge, we can just start again and it will still be better that re-computing the whole sequence.

This definitely meets the second two requirements of the question:

B) there are no consecutive values

C) all 4 values appear equal amount of times

The question is whether it meets the first 'Random' requirement.

If we take the simplest version of the problem, with the input of `[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]` then there are 864 valid permutations (empirically determined!). If we run both methods over 100,000 runs, then we would expect a Gaussian distribution around 115.7 draws per permutation.

As expected, the pure rejection sampling method gives this:

[image]

However, my algorithm does not:

[image]

There is clearly a bias towards certain samples.

In the end, it depends on the requirements. Both methods sample over the whole distribution so both fill the core requirements of the problem. I have not included performance comparisons, but for anything other than the simplest of cases, I am confident that my algorithm would be much faster. However, the distribution of the draws is not perfectly uniform. Whether it is *good enough* is dependent on the application and the size of the actual problem.

Comment: That is not rejection sampling and it generates possible instances with different probabilities.

Comment: Yeah, convergence problem too with something like `[1, 2, 2]`. If `1` gets picked first, not feasible.

Comment: @zelanix +1, good points on randomness and empirical data on the distributions.